# Why Post Back Is taking Too Long time to retrieve data from linked server

Tags: c#, asp.net, linked-server, autopostback, textchanged

I am working with a portal which have grid view and inside grid view i have two text box lets name as txtEmployeeNumber and txtEmployeeName. And i have created an event text_changed on txtEmployeeNumber so that after post back second text will fill respective data such as EmployeeName Please guide me what should i change in that. I tried `OPENQUERY` which is handled at the source (linked server) but not working as accepted. Is there any another approach to retrieve data as fast as possible.

I also use trace and trigger on page and inside my UpdatePanel respectively

`Trace="true"`

and

`<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtEmployeeNumber" EventName="TextChanged" />
 </Triggers>`

in my aspx page for fast postback but no any changes i found

**My Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_Get_Employee_Name]  
 @Employee_ID nvarchar(max)  
AS  
BEGIN  

 DECLARE @emp_name nvarchar(max)  
 SELECT @emp_name = Employee_Name FROM [938.987.644.336].[something].[dbo].[tbl_Employee]  
 WHERE Personnel_Number= @Employee_ID  

 IF (@emp_name is  null or @emp_name = '')  
 BEGIN  
  SELECT @emp_name = Name from [938.987.644.336].[something].[dbo].[tbl_Contract1_Employee]  
  WHERE [Unique id]= '110'+ @Employee_ID  
 END  

 SELECT @emp_name AS Employee_Name  
END
```

**C# code :**

```
protected void txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string EmployeeNo = "";
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    continue;

                EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Get_Employee_Name", Con.OpenConnection());
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", EmployeeNo);
                Con.OpenConnection();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    (row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName") as TextBox).Text = dt.Rows[0]["Employee_Name"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am really perplexed here _Con.CloseConnection(Con.OpenConnection());_ what are you trying to do?

Comment: Con.CloseConnection(Con.OpenConnection()); its just use for opening and  closing the connection i am getting my output perfectly but its taking too long time

Comment: Anyway, you are also executing the same command two times. There is no point in executing an ExecuteNonQuery method while you are interested in getting back the result from the stored procedure

Comment: i am not inserting any data in table my Stored Procedure returning respective data

Comment: remove unwanted part of my code but still its staking too long time to fetch data

Comment: It appears as though you're executing a stored procedure for each record in a grid. This is arguably the *least efficient* way to get data from a database. How are you getting the data for the grid in the first place? It would be much more efficient to simply join from that query to the table mentioned in your stored procedure at that time and populate your column outside of the UI layer altogether...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify area of blockage then only you optimize your search. Here three scenarios are happening:

1. Text change event fired brower.
2. Text change event on the server in C# .
3. Retrieving data from sql server.

For most of the cases blockage happens in point 2 and 3. Now the best solution is to retrieve the data once in the server and keep in the application variable or in the javascript session (if its not too much) in that case you can avoid point 2 and 3.

But if you have too much data then try using datareader instead of dataset as its faster than dataset. Try these and share your results.

One more point I want to say that on each letter typing you are hitting the server I think you need to find a way so that you don't each on each letter typing instead collectively. I faced it in one of my project, so I used some jquery library for the same.

Comment: no not too much data ; Retrieving only one data from Stored procedure that is Employee_Name on basis of Employee_ID

Comment: Then the best way is to retrieve and store the data in the java script object then it will be superfast as you have avoided the server hit.

Comment: Please share any idea or something any approach of javascript ? if you can

Comment: Which technology you are using?

Comment: Sql server 2012 , visual studio 2019, C#, Framework 4.5 (Asp.net), html5

Comment: Ok bring all the data on application start and store it into the application state variable. Then on text change use this application state variable to look for data you are getting from user.
Second approach is little lengthy but well optimized you need to use web method approach. You need to make ajax call to the server to reterive the data. It will give you results very fast.

Comment: I am not getting perfectly Please share something code so that i can use and can check as you mention bring all the data on application start how can i ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201095/discussion-between-gaurav-and-nits-patel).